# Moq is not returning desired output

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I have the following Method which returns HttpResponseMessage

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchStatus(string transactionId, JsonPatchDocument<BspStatusDetails> patchDoc)
        {
            var serializedItemToUpdate = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDoc);
            var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, "bsp/updateBlobEntry/" + transactionId)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(serializedItemToUpdate,
                                System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, "application/json")
            };
            var s = _appConfig.MriSubscriberApiBaseUrl;
            var url = request.RequestUri;
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_appConfig.MriSubscriberApiBaseUrl);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", _appConfig.MriSubscriberApiSubscriptionKey);
            var add = httpClient.BaseAddress;
            return await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        }
```

I am trying to return the status code as HttpStatus.OK whenever PatchStatus method is called.... but when debugging I found it is returning HttpStatus.NotFound

This is my test class

```
 public class MriSubscriberService_Test
    {

        private Mock<ILogger<MriSubscriberService>> _loggerMock;
        private IOptions<AppConfiguration> _appconfig;
        private Mock<IMriSubscriberService> _imriSubscriberService;
        private Mock<ILogger> _logger;
        MriSubscriberService _mriSubscriberService;
        public MriSubscriberService_Test()
        {
            _logger = new Mock<ILogger>();
            _imriSubscriberService = new Mock<IMriSubscriberService>();
            _loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<MriSubscriberService>>();
            _appconfig = TestSetup.GetAppConfiguration();
            _mriSubscriberService = new MriSubscriberService(_loggerMock.Object, _appconfig);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task UpdatedBspStatus_Test()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK};
            _imriSubscriberService.Setup(x => x.PatchStatus(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<JsonPatchDocument<BspStatusDetails>>())).ReturnsAsync(responseMessage);
            bool val = await _mriSubscriberService.UpdatedBspStatus("123", "PROGRESS", "none",_logger.Object);
            Assert.True(val);
        }


    }
```

In the above test method(named UpdatedBspStatus_Test()), the second line must return the status code as HttpStatus.OK. But when I am running it is giving HttpStatus.NotFound.

I am new to Moq and xunit. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you also include the code for your test setup where your're creating the moq and initialising _mriSubscriberService ?

Comment: @auburg sure, I will update my question

Comment: I don't see in your setup where you're passing your mock (_imriSubscriberService) to the service you're testing (_mriSubscriberService) when constructing said service - does your service have IMriSubscriberService property ? How is the mock passed to the service ?

Comment: IMriSubscriberSerivce is an Interface. So to be clear my service(MriSubscriberService) implements IMriSubscriberService interface

Comment: In that case i don't see how this can work - you're testing a concrete implementation of IMriSubscriberService. If you had a test for whatever that's using this service, then you'd have a moq of IMriSubscriberService and the associated setup for the PatchStatus method that you have.